# Suppose that in a group of 10 people, each person has a 0.1 p...

Tags: statistics

> Suppose that in a group of 10 people, each person has a 0.1
>   probability of having a certain disease, independently from person to
>   person. Now consider a testing plan where the group is split into two
>   groups of 5 people where in each group blood samples are taken from
>   each person, then their blood samples are combined and tested together
>   (so there is one test per group of 5). If a group tests positive for
>   the disease then each person in that group is tested individually for
>   the disease, if a group does not test positive, then the testing is
>   concluded for that group. Let the random variable X represent the
>   total number of tests required with this plan.
>
> (a) Determine the probability distribution of X
>
> (b) Consider the more general case where the probability that an
>   individual person has the disease is p. Determine the probability
>   distribution of X in this case.
>
> (c) Consider the even more general case where 2n people are divided
>   into two groups of size n and each person has probability p of having
>   the disease. Determine the probability distribution of X in this case.

Hello!

I'm super sorry for just posting a question with no evidence of me trying to work the problem but I have honestly no idea how to even start this. Is there a possibility of someone finding a question similar to this or to guide me to somewhere where I can learn the concepts that are needed to solve this?

I tried looking for similar questions to (a), (b) and (c) but I was pretty fruitless with my findings.

Thanks so much to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work it through step by step.  Consider the first five subjects.  At least one test is required—the initial group panel.  If *none* of them has the disease (**key question: what is the probability of this?**), no further tests are needed.  But if *any* of them has the disease (one minus the previous probability), a bank of five further tests are needed.  The same is true of the last five subjects.

Thus, there are only three possible numbers of tests: $2$, $7$, and $12$.  They correspond to $0$, $1$, and $2$ extra banks of five tests.  Using your answer to the key question, find out what the probability is of each of those possibilities.